# Proper way to set atime and mtime with fs.utimes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I want to set mtime and atime to the current date, using fs.utimes in nodejs.

Can I just pass it a date object with the current date?  Or do I need to format it differently?

```
var d = new Date();
fs.utimes( path, d, d );
```

Comment: I will clarify my question a bit -- as I am still a little confused after reading that other question...

Comment: Hm, "*Can I just pass it a date object with the current date?*" still is answered in the other thread, isn't it?